# package-info.java package annotations to affect all classes, including ones in sub packages

Tags: java, annotations, package

I want to apply an annotation on all of my classes and I am trying the best way to do so.
So far I am stuck with the package-info.java file that can annotate a whole package, but not the class files contained in the sub-packages. Is there a more efficient way other than adding 100 identical package-info.java files in my project that only contain a single annotation?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is no way to do this.
I have added a static analysis checkstyle check for those package-info.java to make sure they are always there.
See: http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html for more details.
Then if you run checkstyle static analysis on the project, it will complain for any missing package-info.java file.

Finally, to suppress the checkstyle rule on the tests, and on the package where the package annotation definition exists use this suppression rule:

```
<suppress checks="JavadocPackage" files="PackageNonnull.java|[/\\]src[/\\]test[/\\]java[/\\]"/>
```