# Do package-level annotations apply to subpackages?

Tags: java

If I have a tree of packages like so:

```
com.foo
com.foo.bar
com.foo.bar.baz
```

and then I add a `package-info.java` file in `com.foo` and add an annotation to the `com.foo` package, will the annotation also be applied to the children packages, `com.foo.bar` and `com.foo.bar.baz` (and so on)? Or will I need to make another `package-info.java` in each of them with the same annotations?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25391559/package-info-java-package-annotations-to-affect-all-classes-including-ones-in-s?rq=1 (it seems it's does not apply to subpackages)

Comment: The answer is an automatic no given that packages are not a hierarchy - at least not to the JVM. com.foo.bar is not a sibling of com.foo, they're two entirely different packages with zero relations to each other, only a partial overlap in name. They might exist in (multiple) different source bases/jars/projects/universes altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The annotation is not applied to the "children" packages (by my experiment). But it might get implemented in higher versions of Java (see [JEP 104](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/104))